# What does the embed display type do?

Tags: views, 8

I've been trying to find an answer but any search for views embed display brings up a bunch of unrelated modules and questions.

There is a Views Display Type/Mode/Whatever called "Embed" that you select when creating different views in your view:

[image: views embed display]

For what can I use this display type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a display which can be embedded via [views_embed_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.7.x) or drupal_view() of [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

You can embed other display types, too, for example *Page* or *Block*, but the first one generates a route and the second one a block derivate you see when adding blocks to the block layout. So *Embed* is basically a display type which does nothing until you embed it in code.

The only explanation you can find in Views UI is in the general settings, where there is this checkbox:

> [x] Allow embedded displays
>
> Embedded displays can be used in code via views_embed_view().

Which by the way is without function and there is an open [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2760365) to remove it.